# IFrame load() handler gets triggered on declaration on Firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, jquery-events

Having a handler to be triggered on an iframe's `load()`, like this:

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="javascript:'<html></html>'"></iframe>

<form target="iframe"> 
  ...
</form>
```

**JS (with jQuery)**

```
$("#iframe").load(function() {
  console.log("iframe.load called")
});
```

In Chrome: *log* is called when the iframe is loaded (when the `form` with `target` pointing to the iframe is sent) and not called on document load. 
In Firefox: *log* is called when the page is rendered for first time.

I have tried to research but can't explain why would Firefox trigger this handler before the `iframe`'s content is loaded.

Comment: Is it getting called if you leave the `src="javascript:'<html></html>'"` part out?

Comment: @techfoobar right, removing that attribute prevents it. Anyways this handler behaves differently depending on the browser, which is what irks my mind.